# how toset a same generic scale for different 3d models in jpct-ae

Tags: android, scale, augmented-reality, 3dsmax, jpct

In my app, am using JPCT-ae for 3d rendering. I am downloading 3d models form server and rendering it in android device. my problem is some models are small and some are very big. I want to set one generic scale for all the models regardless of what scale they were exported with. so that when i render them on device they should be of same size.

I dont know to do it. please any idea any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: Do you show more then 1 model at the same time?
If not I would just 'zoom extents', to make sure the model / bounding box always fit inside the render window.

Comment: I'm having the same problem. One workaround would be to calculate the model's width and height, and to zoom accordingly to make it fill the GLSurfaceview. But i'm pretty sure there must be a simple workaround to achieve this.